# Are psilocybin/psilocyn the only psychoactive compounds in psychoactive mushrooms?

Tags: pharmacology, mycology

Psilocybe cubensis is the most common psychedelic mushroom, and its active ingredients are psilocin and psilocybin (which is converted to psilocin in the body).

There are other psychedelic mushrooms, such as psilocybe cyanescens, psilocybe mexicana, and amanita muscaria, as well as many others. Are there any other psychoactive compounds in mushrooms other than psilocybin and psilocin?

I found this page but wonder if it is exhaustive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_psychoactive_plants,_fungi,_and_animals?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Welcome to the site. What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not simply to be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Comment: In particular, a Google search in the US for `list of psychoactive compounds in mushrooms` gives 8 different compounds, and there may be more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are multiple psychoactive compounds, including norpsilocin, baeocystin, norbaeocystin, and aeruginascin. Ergot and Fly-Argaric have different substances.

A lot of mushrooms contain [ergot alkaloids](https://academic.oup.com/femsle/article/251/1/9/469557) to defend against nematodes and bacteria.

[Alkaloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaloid) contain Nitrogen. They have biological effects like neurotransmission, circulation, hormonal, immuno-stimulant (lion's mane, chaga mushroom), immuno-depressant.

The psylocin group are very similar isomers:

*Norpsilocin (4-HO-NMT) is tryptamine alkaloid recently discovered in 2017 in the psychedelic mushroom **Psilocybe cubensis**. It is hypothesized to be a dephosphorylated metabolite of baeocystin. Norpsilocin was found to be a full agonist of 5-HT2A receptor. It is also more potent than psilocin.*

***Baeocystin*** is a zwitterionic alkaloid and analog/derivative of psilocybin, and is reported to have similar strength and pharmacology.

Norbaeocystin is a N-demethylated derivative of ***baeocystin***. phosphorylated derivative of 4-hydroxytryptamine. The latter is notable as a positional isomer of serotonin, which is 5-hydroxytryptamine.

Fly-argaric is also psychoactive via muscimol and ibotenic acid, a neurotoxin converting to muscimol after ingestion. Read the wiki page to find out the uses.

[Lion's mane also changes neurotransmission.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28115973/).

To find current research, I suggest googling "neurotransmission funghi" and "funghi neurotoxin".

Flying is not the only measure of helicopters and planes, there's also landing, ground control, maintenance, cost, atmospheric events, efficiency and cargo events.

Comment: What does the last sentence add to your post?

Comment: @AliceD This friendly reminder disguised as an analogy might be referring to 'What goes up must come down' or 'No effect without side-effects'..